# Add Column in Table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to add several columns to an existing table, in which the new column value will be dependent on the value in another column.

I tried this with no luck:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.stores
ADD [STORE TYPE] VARCHAR(20) AS STORETYPE = '5' THEN 'CLOSED' ELSE 'OPEN'
```

I knew it wouldn't be as simple as this, but I thought I'd try before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.stores
ADD [STORE TYPE] AS CONVERT(
  VARCHAR(20), 
  CASE WHEN STORETYPE = '5' THEN 'CLOSED' else 'OPEN' END
);
```

If you want to add multiple columns at once, you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.stores
ADD [STORE TYPE] AS CONVERT(
  VARCHAR(20), 
  CASE WHEN STORETYPE = '5' THEN 'CLOSED' else 'OPEN' END
),
[YOUR MOM] AS CONVERT(
  VARCHAR(20),
  CASE WHEN STORETYPE = 'FAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
);
```

Comment: Can I add more than one column at once?

Comment: @Pweshee Yeah, just separate each `ADD` syntax with a comma.

Comment: @Pweshee updated answer

Comment: Sir, is it possible to join another table in an ALTER TABLE statement? I would like one of the added columns to be conditional on fields in another table, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Pweshee no, that's not possible. Sorry. You could create a view that does this, though.

Comment: your use of parens is going to kill children.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, (oh, you).